# Making Login Api with custom django user model with my defined username and emp_password fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Custom User model authentication does not work for me.
i need to override default password field with my define emp_password field because in database. i have already created users with their passwords field name as emp_password.
I try to map my username and password with employee table emp_password field.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, emp_email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not emp_email:
            raise ValueError('The Email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(emp_email)
        user = self.model(emp_email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, emp_email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """        
        user = self.create_user(
            emp_email,
            password=password,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_admin = True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return self.create_user(emp_email, password, **extra_fields)



class Factory(models.Model):
    factory_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    factory_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    bank = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    branch_contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    swift_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    iban = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    po_box = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    operational_head = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.TextField()
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    company_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    tin = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True) # Taxpayer Identification Number
    pan = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True) # Permanent Account Number
    reg_date = models.DateField()
    status = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default="0")
    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    license_issue_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    license_expiry_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    trash = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reference_num_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reference_num_year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'factory'

class Employee(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    emp_password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    emp_id =  models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    factory = models.ForeignKey(Factory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    emp_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    emp_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    emp_gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    emp_image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    emp_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    emp_per_address = models.TextField()
    emp_city = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    emp_postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    emp_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    emp_thumb_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    emp_designation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    act_designation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    emp_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    emp_guardian_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    emp_joining_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    emp_salary = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    basic_salary = models.FloatField(default='0')
    emp_bank_ac_no = models.CharField(max_length=100 ,null=True, blank=True)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=50 ,null=True, blank=True)
    emp_dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    emp_marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=20 ,null=True, blank=True)
    emp_blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=20 ,null=True, blank=True)
    emp_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0) #'0 -> Active,1 -> Deactive'
    training_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0) # '0 -> traing persuing,a->trainign complete'
    trash = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0) 
    share_factory = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="1")
    emp_father_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="0")
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    drivinglicense = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    experience_years = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    dateofapplication = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    salary_expectation = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    previouscompanyname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    remarks = models.TextField()
    acco_allow = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    trans_allow = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    over_time = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    bank_branch = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    acc_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    joining_date = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    leave_information = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    laborcontractperiod = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    visaperiod      = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    passport_period = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    passport_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    company_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    company_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    company_activity = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    terminated_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    block = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0) # 'Deactive employee . He can not login after block',
    shared_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    login_active = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1) #'0 -inactive , 1 active'
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    annual_leave_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sick_leave_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    annual_leave_count_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sick_leave_count_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_working_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True) #'Sales Team, ECS, Management'
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'emp_email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["emp_email"]

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'employee'
    
    
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.emp_email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.emp_email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = "%s %s" % (self.emp_first_name, self.emp_last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Return the short name for the user."""
        return self.emp_first_name
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "login_app.Employee"
```

Remember tables already created

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import ExampleView, UserLoginApiView
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/',ExampleView.as_view()),
    path('', UserLoginApiView.as_view()),
]
```

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken

class ExampleView(APIView):
    # authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': str(request.user),  # `django.contrib.auth.User` instance.
            'auth': str(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print("request,", request['username'])
        content = {
            'user': str(request.user),  # `django.contrib.auth.User` instance.
            'auth': str(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)




class UserLoginApiView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """ user login api """
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

Comment: You have to work around making your own `CustomLoginBackend` for that purpose, by default in Django, a password field is always required to log in

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70882339/any-possibility-to-put-condition-on-password-required-in-django-custom-auth, This might solve ur problem. @kashif check this out.

Comment: @FaisalNazik not fixed still issue